# Is there a means of showing when I last flushed the DNS cache (in Sierra)?

Tags: caching, dns

I am trying to establish when I last flushed the DNS cache, if it was less than a couple of days ago.

I looked on "chrome://net-internals/#dns" and I get nothing except the option to "clear host cache". I looked at firefox's "about:networking#dns" and I don't get any times, just a list of hostnames. I also tried

```
 sudo dscacheutil -statistics
```

but get

> Unable to get details from the cache node

I am not good with computers, and may have flushed the cache in the process.

Comment: "may have flushed the cache in the process" why is that a problem? Most of the entries are short-lived and would be purged regularly anyway, upon new request it will be fetched from the configured DNS resolver.

Comment: ok. i was just hoping to find a record of the last time i flushed the cache... so some sort of record of stuff that has not been reset @Martheen sorry